# Proof that if $f(x)=o(|g(x)|)$ for $x\to a$, then also $f(x)=O(|g(x)|)$ for $x\to a$.

Tags: analysis

Let $f,g$ be continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Proof that if $f(x)=o(|g(x)|)$ for $x\to a$, then also $f(x)=O(|g(x)|)$ for $x\to a$.
I know that if $f(x)=o(|g(x)|)$ for $x\to a$, that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0.
\end{equation*}
I get intuitively that this means that there exists a $C>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq C|g(x)|$ (and thus $f(x)=O(|g(x)|)$). But I wouldn't know how to write a formal proof.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Your proof is good (but replace $C|f(x)|$ by $C|g(x)|$).

Comment: This is just definition of limit. $h(x)\to 0$ means $|h(x)-0|<\epsilon$, this epsilon is your $C$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that: \begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0
\end{equation*} 
By definition of limit we have that for $\epsilon=\frac12, \exists \delta\gt 0: 0\lt|x-a|\lt \delta\implies |\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}|\lt \frac 12 $ 
So $|f(x)|\lt \frac 12 |g(x)|\implies |f(x)|\le \frac 12 |g(x)|\implies f(x)=O(g(x))$

Answer (score 0):

From

$$\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0
\end{equation*}$$

we see that $f/g$ is bounded in a neighborhood $U$ of $a$. Hence, there is $C>0$ such that

$$|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}| \le C$$

for all $x \in U.$ This gives $f(x)=O(|g(x)|)$ for $x \to a.$